# What is the labeling scheme on these outlets?

Tags: electrical, wiring

This is in a hotel, where there are obviously many, many circuits to manage. Can we tell what information is encoded in these labels?

[image]

Comment: Not an answer (can new users not leave 'comments'?) but... If I read bottom labels on the telecom connectors correctly, one contains a 'V' and the other a 'D' - I bet that's 'Voice' (telephone) and 'Data' (computer networking).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the first plug, the `GLD` is the panel name, and the `15,17,19` is the breaker spaces that it takes.  It is a 3 phase receptacle, but I cannot tell you what NEMA configuration it is.

Same goes for the 20 amp receptacle next to it, `1LB` is the panel name and the `11` is the space in the panel the breaker is in.

The telcom labeling probably leads you the same way.

Comment: Awesome. Can you guess what the GLD and 1LB stand for?

Comment: Also, are those labels required by code, or just a common convention?

Comment: Panel names, I'm not sure about.  They were given before the hotel was built but would make sense if you had the plans, looking at the main feeds and locations.  I don't think the labels are code, just a smart hotel engineer.

Comment: GLD = ground level, D; 1LB = first level, B